# How to convert cell array into desired size matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, diagonal

I have 5x5 cell created from an iterative vector outputs in matlab. The values are diagonally positioned.

[image: current situation]

I need to expand the cells in their columns. I need this.

[image: desired situation]

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can embed the images directly in your question. See this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question

Comment: But to answer your question, it's pretty easy: `x = cellfun(@(y) y(y~=0), c,'UniformOutput',false)`

Comment: thanks. I don't have the privilege to post/embed images directly yet.

Comment: Okay, I see. My bad.

Comment: Thanks, I have diagonal ones. How can I make the rest zeros?

Comment: 1 [] [] [] []
[] 1 [] [] []
[] [] 1 [] []
[] [] [] 1 []
[] [] [] [] 1

Comment: `x = cellfun(@(z) ~isempty(z), cellfun(@(y) y(y~=0), c,'UniformOutput',false),'UniformOutput',false)`

Comment: How do you go from that cell array to that diagonal matrix?  What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Well it isn't particularly general but it does technically produce the result OP asked for... But yeah, I agree it doesn't make sense. I would delete it if I could

Comment: @transversalitycondition nah nah the comment was for the OP. Your answered the question to the best of your ability and with an extreme lack of information.  I'm tempted to vote to close this question as unclear because I have no idea how the OP wishes to go from the cell array to the numeric matrix.

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah... it's not clear from the question what possible cases the solution is supposed to cover. But my comment is still pretty stupid, in retrospect.

Comment: ray@yeah it does not make sense actually. Thanks a lot to 'transversality condition'. I'll delete this question.

Comment: the question was definitely unclear. example was poorly picked. if I have the  {1,1} as say [1,0.5,0.6], all I wanted to know is if I can make it a vector along column 1, so that, A(1,1)=1, A(2,1)=0.5, A=(3,1)=0.6. Like this.